# InvalidCastException in DBContext.Seed() during EF migration update for specific migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an Entity Framework project with 14 migrations. These all work fine: I can update the database to every migration I want, up or down.

Now, if I change a single thing about the model (for instance, add an integer property), add a new migration, and call update-database, the update call fails because an InvalidCastException is thrown in the dbcontext.seed method: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider' to type 'WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider'."

The line it fails on is:

```
var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
```

What I don't understand is why this all works fine when the seed method (containing the same line) is called in those other 14 migrations, but fails as soon as I update the database to the new one. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you update a NUGET package or change the web.config? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143329/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-web-security-sqlroleprovider-to-type-web

Comment: I did not... The only change is the new int property and the resulting migration.